# Problem Using Sifr - Invisible Text

Tags: javascript, flash, sifr

I'm trying to use sIFR for the first time and I have bit of a problem.  Without the sIFR CSS included (I'm trying to get everything right first) the selected element just gets pushed down to make way for the sIFR text, but it's not visible.

Any idea what could be going wrong?

Cheers,

Jon

Comment: Don't you need the CSS included to make it work?

Comment: Could you post an example page?

Answer (score 0):

The CSS file and the Javascript work in tandom.  If you include one without the other, you won't have "everything right first", you'll have some horrible mess whereby *some* of the necessary steps to make sIFR work are happening, and *some* are not.

That seems to be what is happening here - the Javascript dynamically flags certain divs etc. and adjusts what it can, then the CSS rules kick in on these modified entities and format them appropriately.  Without the CSS you're going to have mangled entities hanging potentially all over the place - which is indeed what you're seeing.

So no problems here other than the fact you've decided to invent your own incomplete deployment procedure. ;-)

Comment: From the guide I'm following (in The Art and Science of CSS, Sitepoint) it leads you to start without the CSS so you will see a double entry of the element you're replacing.  After adding the CSS I can now, predictably, see nothing.

Comment: My only suggestion then is that you don't have an appropriate Flash vwersion installed - or it's being blocked by something like the FlashBlock plugin - so the sIFR movie is not being rendered properly.  Inspect the DOM with Firebug and see what's being rendered where.